# transition for box-shadow not working in Opera

Tags: css, opera, css-transitions

I can't get CSS3 transitions for box-shadow to work in Opera. My code:

```
    .shadow {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    -moz-transition: -moz-box-shadow 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.5s;
    -o-transition:  box-shadow 0.5s;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
    }
    .shadow:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,235,255,0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,235,255,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,235,255,0.8);
    }
```

I made e preview in jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dcwAR/

Comment: Works fine for me in Opera 11.60

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this

```
-o-transition:  box-shadow 0.5s;
```

should be this

```
-o-transition:  -o-box-shadow 0.5s;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in Opera 11.62, which is the latest final release.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like support of box-shadow came in in version 10.62, presto 2.6:

http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto26/

So I would check your browser version.

Comment: It's the transition to box-shadow they need help with.

Comment: I am using Opera 11.61 Just like puppybeard said, I need help with the transition.